# python image library PIL on heroku doesn't work

Tags: python-imaging-library

I'm really not sure it's PIL's problem or not. But guessing from it works on local and below error massages, I thought heroku or PIL make trouble.

```
2020-07-04T10:48:48.751781+00:00 app[web.1]: pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (127, 'tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory')
```

and this is my code

```
import pytesseract

import io
import requests
from PIL import Image
response = requests.get("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6a/Tesseract_v3.02.png/500px-Tesseract_v3.02.png")
image_bytes = io.BytesIO(response.content)

img = Image.open(image_bytes)

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'tesseract'
t = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(t)
```

Comment: What is your OS? You may have deprecated version of the package. Look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/895897/error-while-loading-shared-libraries-libpng12-so-0) where a user had similar error.

Comment: heroku i.e. Ubuntu-like OS.